# Got stuck with creating Input Type Text

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and i got stuck with creating Input Type Text.

I have tried this and it does n't work in my case. I mean the space and the button were created but i am not allowed to type into the space anything.

```
<input name="test" type="text" maxlength="200" id="test"/>
       <button onclick="test()"> test button </button>
```

I will write the fuction `test()` later on.

[Here is webpage full code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvQ0YyNTEyVTNDWEk)

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Strictly speaking your code works: you ask for "creating text input" and that's what your code does. Please specify what issues are you experiencing and which is the desired behavior. | Also, in the text editor you have this `[<>]` button which allows you to create a working code snippet, you can just paste your code there instead of linking an external source.

Comment: Please try adding code sample using tools liks (http://jsfiddle.net/) it helps to write code solutions.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example.

Comment: Your issue is CSS related, not JavaScript: remove `pointer-events: none;` rule from the `#info` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot input text into your input is because of this:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

at your "info" style.

That prevents the mouse click to select the input box and enable typing into it because your input is inside the "info" div.

You could add the "pointer-events: all;" style to your input to solve the problem:

```
<input name="test" type="text" maxlength="200" id="test" style="pointer-events: all;"/>
```